# I created a custom maven plugin and I want to use it in gradle project so so is that possible?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I created a custom maven plugin, and I want to use it in a Gradle project so is that possible?

1. do I need to create entirely new Gradle plugin?
2. If I need to create a new Gradle plugin, can I use a Java maven project as a dependency in that plugin?

I created a maven plugin using mojo and that plugin uses some Java maven projects as a dependency.

So can I use that maven plugin in a Gradle project?

Comment: 1. Yes. Maven plugins do not run in Gradle. 2. Yes. You can use a dependency in gradle...

Comment: @khmarbaise So Can I use a maven dependency in gradle to create a new Gradle plugin?

Comment: If this code is not specific for Maven yes of course...